# Create xml file with dataset like this format

Tags: c#, xml

Create xml file with dataset like this format-

```
-<_XPXML Note="" CrtTime="" CN="" DBN="" Srv="" Ver="" AppId="" Class="" IC="" Stock="" Desc="">

<_InvTrans IC="010006" Stock="1" Desc="2 " OppKind="1" Amount="744" Batch="6" Mat="108208"/>
<_InvTrans IC="010006" Stock="1" Desc="2 " OppKind="1" Amount="744" Batch="6" Mat="108208"/>
<_InvTrans IC="010006" Stock="1" Desc="2 " OppKind="1" Amount="744" Batch="6" Mat="108208"/>

</_XPXML>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also specify what you have already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please put a little effort into making the question understandable and also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create some custom xml that you can use XElement.

> How to create `<_XPXML Note="" CrtTime="" CN="" DBN="" Srv="" Ver="" AppId="" Class="" IC="" Stock="" Desc="">`?

You can use the code below to create.

```
var node=new XElement("_XPXML ");
node.SetAttributeValue("Note","");
node.SetAttributeValue("CrtTime","");
// ...
// please write the Attribute
doc.Root.Add(node);
```

Before you use the code that you should new doc as this code

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
```

And you should add `using System.Xml.Linq` in file top.

After you set the attribute that you can save it to file.

```
doc.Save(xx);
```

The example:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement node = new XElement("_XPXML");
node.SetAttributeValue("Note", "");
var invTrans = new XElement("_InvTrans");
node.Add(invTrans);
invTrans.SetAttributeValue("IC", "010006");

doc.Add(node);

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
TextWriter stream = new StringWriter(str);
doc.Save(stream);
```

The `str` is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<_XPXML Note="">
  <_InvTrans IC="010006" />
</_XPXML>
```

Comment: tnx lindexi .after that how can i add elements like that format.

Comment: As you can see that the node is the `_XPXML ` that you can run the code to see what it output.

Comment: @lindexi One of the reasons you shouldn't answer low quality questions is that you might end up with a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258208/3214843) and encourage that person to ask more questions of that kind in the future (since they got what they needed the last time).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Ok, for I edit his question and that I think I can answer this.

Comment: @lindexi And there is nothing wrong with trying to help people - that's what SO is for. I'm just trying to warn you, that you might be wasting your with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try following using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("_InvTrans");
            dt.Columns.Add("IC", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Stock", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OppKind", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Batch", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Mat", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "010006", "1", "2 ", "1", "744", "6", "108208" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "010006", "1", "2 ", "1", "744", "6", "108208" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "010006", "1", "2 ", "1", "744", "6", "108208" });
            GetXmlTable(dt);

        }
        static XElement GetXmlTable(DataTable dt)
        {
            string tableName = dt.TableName;
            XElement table = new XElement(tableName);

            string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement xRow = new XElement("_InvTrans");
                table.Add(xRow);
                foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
                {
                    xRow.Add(new XAttribute(columnName, row[columnName]));
                }
            }

            return table;

        }

    }

}
```